# How to manipulate this JSON array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a JSON array like:

```
var data = {
  name: 'Mike',
  level: 1,
  children: [
    { name: 'Susan',
      level: 2,   },
    { name: 'Jake',
      level: 2    },
    { name: 'Roy',
      level: 2 },
    ]
  }
```

How could i add a children array to Jake so that the array would then look like:

```
var data = {
  name: 'Mike',
  level: 1,
  children: [
    { name: 'Susan',
      level: 2,   },
    { name: 'Jake',
      level: 2,
      children: [ 
             { name: 'Angela',
               level: 3 }   
                ] 
    },
    { name: 'Roy',
      level: 2 },
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not JSON, that's a Javascript object. JSON is a text format for representing data.

First you would need to find Jake. He is in the `data.children` array, so look there:

```
var i = 0;
while (data.children[i].name != 'Jake') i++;
```

(That code assumes that Jake is actually somewhere in the array.)

Now you can add a property to the object, which is an array of objects:

```
data.children[i].children = [ 
  { name: 'Angela', level: 3 }   
];
```

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish the code `data.children[i].children = [ 
  { name: 'Angela', level: 3 }   
];` with the `push` function ?

Comment: @rage: First you need the property to be an array: `data.children[i].children = [];`. Then you can push objects into it: `data.children[i].children.push({ name: 'Angela', level: 3 });`.

Answer (score 0):

```
data.children[1].children = [{name: 'Angela',level: 3 }]
```